# How to detect stylus hover and/or toggle the touchscreen on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, touchscreen, wacom, wayland, xinput

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S1. It has a wacom pen and I need to be able to use it to take notes but there is inadequate palm rejection. At the least I need to be able to run a script to toggle the touchscreen. Ideally I would like to run a Bash or Python script to detect when the Wacom pen is hovering and disable the touchscreen.

I am on a new Ubuntu 17.10 installation: I previously used 17.10 with X, not wayland, but it became unstable and I reinstalled. I was using a [python script](https://github.com/ragtag/spin) before which could toggle the touchscreen when the pen was hovering, however this does not work in wayland.

Turning off the touchscreen with xinput causes me to be logged out or sometimes crashes the OS.

How can I toggle the touchscreen on wayland?
Can I detect when the stylus is hovering?